# Second drop-down content dependent on first drop-down

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select

On my web page I want to have two drop-downs, where if you select different options from the first drop-down, different options will appear in the second drop-down.

For example, 
  if **Category A** is chosen in drop-down 1, 
  I want **A1**, **A2**, **A3** to appear in drop-down 2. 
     If **Category B** is chosen in drop-down 1, 
     I want **B1**, **B2**, **B3** to appear in drop-down 2.

If my HTML has these lines of text:

```
<select id="independent">
  <option value="CatA"> A </option>
  <option value="CatB"> B </option>
</select>

<select id="dependent">
  <option value="A021"> A1 </option>
  <option value="A22019"> A2 </option>
  <option value="A3541"> A3 </option>
  <option value="B148"> B1 </option>
  <option value="B2"> B2 </option>
  <option value="B397415"> B3 </option>
</select>
```

How would I implement what I want as described above, using JavaScript/jQuery?

Answer (score -1):

Use the jQuery event .on and listen to a change in the selectbox 1. If the selected option is changed, look up which value was selected and then modify your second selectbox regarding to the selected option.

Here's a simple snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dependent > option").hide();

  $(document).on('change', '#independent', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    console.log(val);
    $("#dependent > option").show();
    if (val == 'CatA') {
      $("#dependent > option").each(function() {
        var optionVal = $(this).val();
        var letter = optionVal.charAt(0);
        //console.log(letter);
        if (letter == 'B')
          $(this).hide();
      });
    } else if (val == 'CatB') {
      $("#dependent > option").each(function() {
        var optionVal = $(this).val();
        var letter = optionVal.charAt(0);
        //console.log(letter);
        if (letter == 'A')
          $(this).hide();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="independent">
  <option value=""> Select </option>
  <option value="CatA"> A </option>
  <option value="CatB"> B </option>
</select>

<select id="dependent">
  <option value=""> Select </option>
  <option value="A1"> A1 </option>
  <option value="A2"> A2 </option>
  <option value="A3"> A3 </option>
  <option value="B1"> B1 </option>
  <option value="B2"> B2 </option>
  <option value="B3"> B3 </option>
</select>
```